# Cannot debug project after upgrading to Service Fabric SDK v2.3.301

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Recently upgraded to Service Fabric SDK v2.3.301, but for some reason my project got corrupted. I cannot debug the project, I get the following error: "A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started."

It seems that the solution now fails to recognize the Service Fabric App. Yet I am able to deploy to my local cluster.

Anyone had similar issues while upgrading to the new SDK?

Thanks

PS Just in case, the service fabric app is the already set as startup project :o)

Comment: Mind posting your .sfproj?

Comment: Are you using multiple start-up projects? Is one of the class libraries in the solution also configured as a start-up project?

Comment: Hi @JZimmerman, No I am not using multiple start-up projects. I have check this many times :o( . But as soon as I click debug (ie, F5), it changes my configuration and makes a "Domain DLL" Project as the start-up project. I am a little bit lost.

Comment: Hi @VaclavTurecek, it seems that the .sfproj is too long to paste here. Is there a section that might point you in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We have been using Service Fabric to develop a product for about a year with various versions of the SDK and I see this frequently. It happens both when hitting F5 with the SF Application as the sole startup project and even when right-clicking the SF Application and choosing "Debug -> Start New Instance".

Sometimes I have to try several times before it finally works. Other developers in our team see this as well, going all the way back to v2.0.

One thing that *seems* to make it happen less frequently is not touching **anything** on your computer after launching the project. Don't click anything else. Don't select another window. Let go of the mouse. Don't touch the keyboard.

Something I've started doing on the advice of a colleague is choosing "Debug -> Start Without Debugging", then attaching to the process if I want to debug it. I've had better luck with this approach in general - including not getting the "A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started" issue.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same issue a couple of times. I have not been able to identify the source. But I have solved it with the following actions:

1. Close all Visual Studio windows.
2. Restart the Service Fabric service: Type services.msc in the windows run tool. Find Microsoft Service Fabric Host Service. Right Click + Restart.
3. Reset the local cluster: Look at the Service Fabric Local Cluster Manager Icon in the notification area in the right side of the task bar. Right Click + Reset Local Cluster.
4. Open the problematic solution in Visual Studio.
5. Clean and Rebuild solution.
6. Finally run your solution (press F5).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

The error indicates that the service fabric application project (*.sfproj) is not set as start up project. Please try to change the start up project as some other project and again change it back to service fabric application project and see if that resolves the issue.