# Cannot debug Service Fabric

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I have a statesless Service Fabric service

I am deploying it within my application into a  1 node dev cluster

None of my breakpoints ever get hit

I have rebuilt, restarted, updated visual studio and I am now really out of ideas

Has anyone ever seen this?

The strange thing is that my breakpoints stay active

I know my logic is being executed as messages are shown in the console

Paul

Comment: does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42118286/5946937

Comment: Yep thanks seems to work ok now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linking the answer in the comments

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42118286/5946937

1. Close all Visual Studio windows.
2. Restart the Service Fabric service: Type services.msc in the windows run tool. Find Microsoft Service Fabric Host Service. Right Click + Restart.
3. Reset the local cluster: Look at the Service Fabric Local Cluster Manager Icon in the notification area in the right side of the task bar. Right Click + Reset Local Cluster.
4. Open the problematic solution in Visual Studio.
5. Clean and Rebuild solution.
6. Finally run your solution (press F5).

Answer (score 0):

There is one other thing that I noticed. After pressing an F5, on the process tab, keep an eye on the process id [image](this is just a sample reference, not from a service fabric process), in my case, there were no processes attached at all. In such a case, go to Debug -> Attach to Process -> Choose the process you need to debug.
[image]
One thing to keep in mind is that sometimes you may have to select the **show process from all users** checkbox because visual studio may be running in admin  mode but the application process maybe running in normal user mode.
[image]

You can also understand that the right process has not been attached when you see something like this [image] in front of the breakpoint. This is also an indication that the right process has not been attached. If the right process has been attached, the debugging should be successful!